# What is our stance on the use of copyrighted photos as profile pictures?

Tags: discussion, profile-picture, copyright

I asked [this](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/does-the-photo-use-apply-to-profile-pictures) question on Aviation.Meta, but it has not gotten much attention so I am posting here a modified version of it.

**Scenario:** A person joins a SE Community, and puts up or uploads a photo for, say his, profile picture on that community. However, the photo that person uses is under copyright.

How should we deal with such a situation?